# How to get true y_true and y_pred inside on_epoch_end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to get y_true and y_pred at the end of each epoch. I use fit_generator to train my model. I am trying to find the specificity after each epoch.

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      y_true = ?
      y_pred = ?

loss_history = LossHistory

fit_generator(train_data, .. callbacks=[loss_history])
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to this information by default, but you can give a `Callback` whatever attributes you want to by passing them to the constructor. For example, if you're using a generator (with data stored in the `generator.y` attribute):

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, data_generator, **kwargs):
        self.generator = data_generator
        Super(LossHistory, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_true = self.generator.y
        y_pred = self.model.predict_generator(self.generator)


loss_history = LossHistory(train_data_generator)
```

Comment: its train_data_generator not validation_data_generator right?

Comment: With this implementation you could use whatever generator you like. (It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted training or validation loss information.)

Comment: this works fine if the model is small size, however, if the model is large it gets an OMM error..tf doesnt release the memory before predicting..